# swift change text in UITableViewHeaderFooterView upon selecting a row

Tags: swift, xcode

im trying to change my header label to nameLabelText ( a var of type string i set when i click on a row) when i call didselectrow , and now when i do select a row the did set is called and it print out the string that i want it to be but it just doesn't upload the label?

```
 var nameLabelText: String? {
    didSet{
        print("did set nameLabelText",nameLabelText as Any)
        nameLabel.text = nameLabelText

      reloadInputViews()
    }
}

 lazy var nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Search Refinements"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    return label
}()
```

Comment: Can you show code of `didSelectRowAt` method?

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            print("Online Users Only Selected")
            
           let csh = ConntectionStatusHeader()
          
            csh.nameLabelText = "Search Refinements - Online Users Only "
            
           
            
          
        }else............

Comment: Please update `didSelectRowAt` to your question. What are you using `ConntectionStatusHeader` for? It's a `headerView` or `footerView`. Can you write down how you create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you want change text of header label, you create a new `ConntectionStatusHeader` by

`let csh = ConntectionStatusHeader()`

instead of get current `ConntectionStatusHeader`.

To fix it, when clicking a cell, get `ConntectionStatusHeader` you want to change label and change text of its label. Try this below code with your `didSelectRowAt` method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if indexPath.row == 0 {
    print("Online Users Only Selected")
    let csh = tableView.headerView(forSection: indexPath.section) as! ConntectionStatusHeader;
    csh.nameLabelText = "Search Refinements - Online Users Only "
  } else {
    // Do what you want
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome @bennypalms661 ;)